# JS Regex: Validate File Names

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm working to validate Image file names (png, png, Jpg ..), I wrote this regex to prevent double dotes in file names contains English and Unicode numbers spaces

```
[^\w][\.](gif|jpe?g|png)$
```

Test case and samples exits on this LINK on Refex101 [regex101 samples](https://regex101.com/r/buKxuc/1)

- test.png --> not passing
- test .png
- اختبار .png
- اختبار.png
- test.png --> not passing

please advise

Comment: Can you explicitly state what your regex should match and what shouldn't match? It doesn't look clear what your expected behaviour is at the moment.

Comment: Aren't you looking for something like this `^(.+)[\.](gif|jpe?g|png)$`

Comment: This is actually trickier than you'd expect because some image files on the web don't end with an extension eg. https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/meme-mesheen.appspot.com/o/memes%2FAdmin1675602054309?alt=media&token=ac2be040-9c8c-4dbf-a068-607afb86fa2a

Comment: @HassanImam unfortuantlity it will allow dout dots means filename.exe.png

Comment: @lemon regex to validate file name to contain English and Unicode carachters, numbers, spaces .. without dote dots (filename.exe.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
/^[\w\s\p{L}]+\.(gif|jpe?g|png)$/u;
```

`\p{L}` - matches any unicode letter

`u` - flag to enable unicode